# How do I fix issue on overlapping components in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

On my main xml file, I have these four components arranged this way:

```
<fragment...>

<RelativeLayout...>

<Button...>

<androidx.drawerLayout.widget.DrawerLayout...>
```

Since the DrawerLayout is on the topmost layer of my whole screen, (although it looks transparent) it covers all of my other components such as those inside the RelativeLayout which makes it impossible to click. However, if I move it to the bottom of the component tree, the RelativeLayout covers it which is also not what I want.

I figured that there could be two ways in which I could solve the issue. First by moving the whole RelativeLayout inside the DrawerLayout resulting to visual error of the RelativeLayout stretching all the way to the top of the screen, or by making the DrawerLayout clickthrough. Which of the two is most efficient way of doing it and how can I do it?

Here is the entire xml file of my activity:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_border"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/markerOrigin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonOrigin"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="121dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/originMarkerDescription"
            map:srcCompat="@drawable/usersloacationbb" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/markerDestination"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDestination"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/destinationMarkerDescription"
            map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            map:srcCompat="@drawable/destinationbb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOrigin"
            android:layout_width="215dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDestination"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonTara"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonOrigin"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTara"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_tara"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
            android:text="@string/buttonTara"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDrawer"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="270dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer">
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's how it looks like with the DrawerLayout on the topmost layer:
Correct display but unclickable components

[image]

Here's how it looks like with RelativeLayout inside the DrawerLayout:
Correct arrangement of components but with padding issues on the button

[image]

Here's how it looks like with the DrawerLayout on the bottom:
DrawerLayout below other components

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clickable content and on top drawer you must move ConstraintLayout
into DrawerLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/markerOrigin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonOrigin"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-22dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="121dp"
                android:contentDescription="originMarkerDescription"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/markerDestination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDestination"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
                android:contentDescription="destinationMarkerDescription"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonOrigin"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="215dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:text="lk;'kl;'" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonDestination"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttonTara"
                android:layout_below="@+id/buttonOrigin"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:text="lk;'kl;'"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTara"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="buttonTara"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDrawer"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="270dp"
            android:text="lk;'kl;'"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/main"></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```